# Despite initialization, lateinit property has not been initialized in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Grettings,
I have a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter that pulls data from Firestore. Until the data is pulled, I want to show a skeletonView which works conveniently. To notify the Fragment when data is pulled, I use a listener. However, when I override the method of this listener interface in the Fragment, for some reason I get "kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property rvShops has not been initialized" for my recyclerView, even though they are initialized by the time the interface method is triggered. My code snippets are as follows:

```
class ShopsFragment : Fragment(), ShopsLoadedListener {
companion object {
    fun newInstance(): ShopsFragment {
        return ShopsFragment()
    }
}

private lateinit var colRefShops: CollectionReference
private lateinit var shopAdapter: ShopAdapter
private lateinit var v: View
private lateinit var b: FragmentShopsBinding
private lateinit var skeleton: Skeleton

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
    }
    (activity as MainActivity).tabLayoutShops.visibility = View.GONE
    colRefShops = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(DB_SHOPS)

}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shops, container, false)
    return v
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initRecyclerView()
}

  override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    shopAdapter.startListening()
}

private fun initRecyclerView() {
    rvShops?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(v.context, 2)
    skeleton = skelOutShops
    skeleton = rvShops.applySkeleton(R.layout.item_shop, 10)
    skeleton.showSkeleton()

    val q: Query = colRefShops.orderBy(WEIGHT)
    val options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ModelShop> =
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelShop>()
            .setQuery(q, ModelShop::class.java)
            .build()
    shopAdapter = ShopAdapter(options, shopsLoadedListener = newInstance())

}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    shopAdapter.stopListening()
}

override fun onShopsLoaded(i: Int) {

    Log.d("dataComes", "Data = $i")
    rvShops.adapter = shopAdapter //here i get kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property rvShops has not been initialized when this method is fired up
    skeleton.showOriginal()
}
}
```

---

My adapter:

```
class ShopAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ModelShop>, private var shopsLoadedListener: ShopsLoadedListener)
: FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ModelShop, ShopAdapter.ShopViewHolder>(options) {

override fun onDataChanged() {
    super.onDataChanged()
    shopsLoadedListener.onShopsLoaded(5)
}

private var v: View? = null
public interface ShopsLoadedListener{
    fun onShopsLoaded(i: Int)
}


class ShopViewHolder(private val b: ItemShopBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(b.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ShopViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_shop, parent, false)
    val b = ItemShopBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    Log.d("fire", "ifireincreateviewholder")

    return ShopViewHolder(b)
}

 override fun onBindViewHolder(vHolder: ShopViewHolder, i: Int, modelShop: ModelShop) {
    vHolder.itemView.tvShopName.text = modelShop.displayName
     Glide.with(vHolder.itemView.context)
         .load(modelShop.logoURL)
         .centerCrop()
         .into(vHolder.itemView.ivShopLogo)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you tried to use `skeleton` before you assigned it a value.  It's almost certainly the case that `onShopsLoaded` was invoked before `initRecyclerView` could initialize it.  You're going to have to write code to detect this case and deal with it correctly.

Comment: That's the weird part. initRecyclerView() is invoked before onShopsLoaded(), my logs in both initRecyclerView() and onShopsLoaded() prove this.  https://i.imgur.com/K5E1SGm.png As you can see here I get a skeleton grid layout right before the crash, and there are two items per row in the grid, which means rvShops?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(v.context, 2) get executed just fine. But when the code inside onShopsLoaded() is triggered, suddenly that rvShops is null. Also if you are saying that skeleton isn't initialized correctly, how come skeleton.showSkeleton() also executes withno error?

Comment: I now get your point btw, I made a mistake by posting with the error message saying that skeleton is not init., but even if I remove everything about the skeletons, the rvShops is also null on the overridden interface method and that's really the point I am trying to make.

Comment: It's going to be fundamentally the same issue, though.  You used rvShops before it was assigned.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/t1MgBrC.png - This is my onViewCreated() now, the issue persists. I am sure that the initialization is done in this case. By same logic when I do "rvShops?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(v.context, 2)", I use rvShops before it was assigned, yet no error is thrown and the code executes as expected. I feel like the problem lies somewhere else and it is specific to the scope of the overridden onShopsLoaded()

Comment: Your code never actually assigns rvShops at all, at least not from what you showed here.

Comment: In that case how should the assignment to rvShops be done? I am assigning it to the recyclerView in fragment_shops.xml, am I missing something? Again, if the assignment was an issue, how can all the code that uses the instance of rvShops in initRecyclerView() can execute and the ones in onShopsLoaded() find the variable null?

Comment: XML cannot assign the values of variables in Kotlin.  You need to write code to find the element in your inflated XML.

Comment: while I am thankful that you are trying to help, I feel like you are not reading what I am saying here. https://i.imgur.com/t1MgBrC.png In this screenshot I literally inflate the element using the usual findViewByID way (which is not even needed when I am using KOE here) yet the issue persists. All my view variables are only problematic in the scope of onShopsLoaded(), do you know why that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're never assigning `rvShops` to anything, which would render it uninitialized. Given that it's set to `lateinit`, it makes sense that you're getting the `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`.

Solution:

Assign `rvShops` in `onViewCreated(...)` in your fragment and this shouldn't be crashing like that anymore.

Comment: What do you mean with assignment? If you are talking about "rvShops = v.findViewById(R.id.rvShops)" like the Java way, I still get "lateinit property rvShops has not been initialized". My onCreateView() is as follows: https://i.imgur.com/t1MgBrC.png

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun initRecyclerView() {
rvShops?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(v.context, 2)
skeleton = skelOutShops
skeleton = rvShops.applySkeleton(R.layout.item_shop, 10)
skeleton.showSkeleton()

val q: Query = colRefShops.orderBy(WEIGHT)
val options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ModelShop> =
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelShop>()
        .setQuery(q, ModelShop::class.java)
        .build()
shopAdapter = ShopAdapter(options, shopsLoadedListener = newInstance())
}
```

Turns out the problem was in this function, particularly the line:

```
shopAdapter = ShopAdapter(options, shopsLoadedListener = newInstance())
```

The correct way to create the instance of this listener should be:

```
shopAdapter = ShopAdapter(options, this)
```

In which case its method that I implement works correctly as well.